# Can I pull down with 5V logic a not-level shifted (which is at 2.8V logic pulled-up) input? How to pull it up to 2.8V again, with no level-shifters?

Tags: microcontroller, level-shifting, output, logic-level, input-impedance

I have a Distance sensor which has an enable pin (XSHUT pin in the diagram) which is pulled high in its own PCB module at 2.8V, to enable it to work. My Attiny85 MCU, which controls the sensor, is at 5V, and the SDA and SCL lines of the sensor are level shifted, so the Attiny works normally with the sensor.

[image]

As I don't have space left in my tiny PCB, I want to know if it's possible to connect this not-level shifted ENABLE input (XSHUT) from the sensor directly to one pin of my Attiny (with no extra components), set the Attiny pin as output and drive it low to make the sensor enter energy saving state when I want it.

But how could I revert back the ENABLE (XSHUT) pin to its original state, where it's pulled high by its own supply at 2.8V and leave the shutdown mode? I can't drive it high directly from the MCU because it's 5V Logic... Could I just set the Attiny pin as an Input then? Would it work?

I don't have space left in my pcb for extra components...

Comment: `Can I pull down with 5V logic` ... pull down is not done with 5 V ... it is done with GND ... imagine placing a mechanical switch between XSHUT pin and GND ... when switch is conducting then XSHUT is LOW ... when the switch is not conducting then the 10 k resistor pulls the XSHUT pin HIGH to whatever voltage Vdd happens to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can work by either pulling the pin low by setting it as a low output, or letting the pin float by setting it as an input without internal pull-up.

Comment: On page 55 of the datasheet (https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf) you can see how to put the pin into the Hi-Z state.

Answer (score 0):

Just about any modern microcontroller will have a mechanism for driving a pin as an open drain output.

Most just have that as a setting. For the ones that do not, you can set the output data to zero, and then toggle the pin between high-Z and low-Z mode.

Then all you need is a pull-up resistor to your 2.8V supply, and things should work.

I am not familiar with your ATtiny, but it sounds like there's a way to do it. Buried in the data sheet someplace.